# create button that pops up on hover

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I've spent a lot of time trying to implement one thing, which is
a button that pops up in the center of a picture when the user's mouse enters the picture block, and when the mouse exits, button should disappear.

I've tried using many different widgets, such as InkWell and MouseArea but sadly didn't get expected behavior

Please share your thoughts if you know how to implement such behavior in flutter

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Should the button appear if the mouse is anywhere inside the picture block? Or should the user see the button if the cursor is in the middle of the picture?

Comment: @TripleNine yes, the button should appear if the mouse is anywhere inside the picture block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `AnimatedContainer`, you could use `AnimatedSwitcher` which switches between a Button and a non-visible `SizedBox` whenever the `onEnter` or `onExit` event is called.

Just change the container to the picture you want to show.

Code example with [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=b2c122daf45a812f7fc8156e60a8f837):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  
  bool showButton = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Material App Bar'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: MouseRegion(
            onEnter: (_) => setState(() {
              showButton = true;
            }),
            onExit: (_) => setState(() {
              showButton = false;
            }),
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.red[200],
                  width: 300,
                  height: 300,
                ),
                AnimatedSwitcher(
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
                  child: showButton ? ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () => print("Hi!"),
                    child: const Text("Hello")
                  ) : const SizedBox.shrink(),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I see that it works just as I wanted at DartPad, but sadly can't reproduce it at my project, everything looks the same except button doesn't pop up, 
mouse region properly registers onEnter and onEnter
could it be the SizedBox that wraps around this code?

Comment: I don't think the `SizedBox` influence the `Button`. Maybe post your new code in your question post. Otherwise it's not easy to tell where the bug is.

Comment: added new code to the question

Comment: You must not set `bool showButton = false` inside this or any method which is called by the `build` method. It must be a field of the state itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, moving this code from the method helped, now it works fine, image somehow blinks when mouse enters it, but the main task is done

Comment: That's maybe because your build method does a lot of computation. You may extract `_getQRWidget` into a new widget. Rebuilding this widget shouldn't be that expensive. You shouldn't use methods to extract widgets anyway.